# Validate Python Pandas Dataframe Column with Row Reference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation

I'm planning to validate columns in my dataframe as follows...

```
def validateCol1(val):
    #validate
    #write invalid entries to my error tracking list with row reference

df['col1'].apply(validateCol1)
```

But although that passes the column value to my function, I want to be able to access the row where the error occured.  Does anyone know how I could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the lambda function to the row instead of only on a single column:

```
df.apply(lambda x: validateCol(x), axis=1)
```

Thus in the `validateCol` function you can access value in column 1 using `x['col1']` and also access other columns in the row.